# Is a Kubernetes Arm Master and x86 nodes wise/possible?

Tags: kubernetes, multiarch, raspberry-pi4

I don't even know if this is possible, but would it be wise?  I don't know, but I think that the master node would not have to handle as much as the worker nodes.  With that assumption I wanted to make my master as energy efficient as possible by moving it to my RPiV4 (has 4GB ram).

Comment: The master architecture doesn't matter. The interface between masters and worker nodes is http.  The only thing you might run into is due to a less used/tested build of kubernetes.

Comment: Please, upvote/accept the answer to let community know about the usefulness, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The building of a hybrid architecture cluster required some improvements from the main Kubernetes distribution provided since version 1.12. Kubernetes had AMD64 and ARM64 images for a while but to be able to transparently create the hybrid cluster, it required that Docker Manifests were pushed to the repositories where the main image tag pointed to the tagged architecture images.
I really recommend you to to look for those articles:

- [x86 and ARM Kubernetes cluster](https://medium.com/@carlosedp/building-a-hybrid-x86-64-and-arm-kubernetes-cluster-e7f94ff6e51d)
- [Multi-arch cluster](https://masterofnone.io/spinupk8/)
- [Multiplatform (amd64 and arm) Kubernetes cluster](https://gist.github.com/squidpickles/dda268d9a444c600418da5e1641239af)

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: could you comment on the implications of a lower powered master?

Comment: You need to know what you want to run on your cluser (one or few apps, kind of apps, CPU vs Memory intensive), than you can decide about architecture. For example if you want to create cluster with kubeadm, for Master node you need fulfill minimum requirements like 2GB or more RAM.

Comment: thank you for taking time to delve into my question. I realize the question is vague. I don't want to run any pod/deployment/service/etc  on the master that isn't necessary. I'm not sure if later I may find that certain things run better if ran locally on the master.  I know that certain things do not *yet* run on the ARM architecture like Istio or Linkerd (at least w/o custom building some images). But as far as I know they don't need to run on the master. I'm looking for experiences that show where it would be beneficial to have a beefier master than that of the nodes or vice versa.

Comment: To add more context, I have since set up my cluster such that the master *is* running on the RPi and haven't noticed anything weird yet.  I'm using K3S if anyone is interested. The install did not require I do anything different in order for it to work properly.